# Active Admin filter on "scoped" queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, rails-activerecord

I'm using ActiveAdmin and I'm trying to set up filter using my own scopes. Here's a sample of model:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_nationality, lambda { |nationality| OtherModel.where(nationality: nationality).map(&:my_model) }
end
```

And here's how I set up the filter:

```
ActiveAdmin.register MyModel do
  filter :nationality
end
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work: the filtering box doesn't contain any nationality filter.
Does anyone know how should I set up this filter, and if it is even possible ?

Thanks !

Comment: What are the columns in MyModel? You can specify/populate the filter like so: `filter :nationality, as: :select, collection: OtherModel.count(group: :nationality).sort_by{|k,v|v}.reverse.collect{  |a|  [ "#{a[0]} (#{a[1]})", a[0] ] }`

Comment: Does MyModel class has no associations to Nationality? ActiveAdmin handles belongs_to accordingly.

Comment: first of all scope should return relation object, your scope returns array ...

Answer (score 2):

first, you need associate OtherModel with MyModel

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :other_model
end
```

you don't need a scope, filter works on associated model

```
ActiveAdmin.register MyModel do
  filter :other_model_nationality
end
```